# Simulate windows drag and drop with code?

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi, drag-and-drop

I think I may have asked a similar question in the past, but I am still stuck...

As part of an automated process, I must "import" a specific subset of media files into a closed-source third-party application (Dartfish, incase it matters). **Here is the situation:**

- The media (video) files are all in one folder (there are 1000s of them, and reorganization is not an option unfortunately).
- On any given iteration of the script I am writing, only 13 *specific* files must be imported into the application.
- There is no import function in the app that must receive the files.
- This same app *does* allow you to drap and drop files into a specific pane, and this allows you to essentially import them.

The current workaround I am using is very unstable and ugly, and uses a complex procedure of regex queries to isolate the files in Xplorer2, and then uses AutoIT to select them, and then finally drag them into the application.

**Proposed Solution:**

I need a way to drag and drop the specific subset of video files I need at any given time into this application, preferably without automating clicks and cursor movement (there are way too many points of failure in this setup).

I am essentially just passing a list of filenames to the application (by dragging them there), so I figure there has got to be a way of automating this drag and drop purely in code - perhaps using C/C#/C++ and the windows API? Bonus points if the solution can be ported to Python somehow... but not necessary.

If anyone can point me in the right direction with this (programming language doesn't matter; I'll learn whatever I need to know), and preferably give me a basic outline or example of how I can accomplish such a task, I would really appreciate it! This has been driving me nuts for over a year now!

Answer (score 2):

1) Inject into target process

2) Get IDropTarget of target window

```
function GetDropTargetFromWnd(AWnd: HWND): IDropTarget;
var Unknow: IUnknown;
begin
  Unknow := IUnknown(GetProp(AWnd, PChar(GlobalFindAtom('OleDropTargetInterface'))));
  if Assigned(Unknow) then
    Unknow.QueryInterface(IDropTarget, Result)
end;
```

3) Create IDataObject with your files

4) Call IDropTarget.DragEnter

5) Call IDropTarget.Drop

**Updated algorithm:**

1) Register your unique message with RegisterWindowMessage

2) Install global hook with SetWindowsHookEx with WH_CALLWNDPROC type (additional dll is required)

3) Create fixed file with 13 names

4) Send unique message registered in steip 1 to target window

5) You hook will be loaded into target process

6) Inside hook procedure check message

7) If message is your unique message

7.1) Get IDropTarget of target window

7.2) Load names from fixed file

7.3) Create IDataObject with your files

7.4) Call IDropTarget.DragEnter

7.5) Call IDropTarget.Drop

8) If all files don’t processed yet then go to 3

9) Uninstall global hook

**Update 2**

Also you can try send WM_DROPFILES message to target window from you hook dll.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... I actually never considered this. Would this be a stable solution (as in, work consistently and not crash the host application)? I have performed trivial DLL injection before, so I am willing to try this...

Comment: Stability will be depend on how you implement the algorithm :)

Comment: Ok, I have managed (in C++, which I am totally unfamiliar with) to inject a DLL. This is the main code for the DLL:

http://pastebin.com/SUz2XvPA

So far I understand how the injection technique I am using works, and how this BASIC structure of a DLL works... but I am now stuck. Two questions: (A): Where should I write the main code that goes in this DLL? Perhaps in the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH case block? ...and (B): How would I go about passing the list of files that I am "dragging-and-dropping" to the DLL after it has been injected? Should I use a temporary file to read the list in? Thank you!

Comment: Alright, I've just started a new job, and have not had time to work on this, so I am sorry for the late reply. I'm reading over your answer, but I am fairly confused... I have no idea how to interpret your answer. If I am understanding correctly (not sure what language the code above is in either), I create a unique message to tell the software when I am sending it files? When it recieves this message, it then performs the Drag and Drop simulation using the hooked windows procedure? A little more explanation wouldn't hurt. Thanks.

Comment: When you send your unique message your hook dll will be loaded into target process. It is injection mechanism. When your hook procedure is called you can do all drag and drop actions you need.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Denis; very busy with new full-time job, and this is a side project. I am still working on implementing your solution, as I have realized it is the most practical one. Just one quick question:  How do I wrap the filenames in an IDataObject? Since it is an interface, would I create a "DATAOBJECT" which implements it by default, and then use that?  Do I need to use the FileDrop data format? Thank you for all your replies, they have really been helpful.

Comment: I don`t know C# or C++. It will be better if you create a new question about IDataObject. Easy solution is SHCreateDataObject function.

Comment: Hey I'm currently facing the same problem, did you try this out? and did it work?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Firefox & Chrome seems to prevent dll injection. Is there a way to achieve this without going about it this way? WM_DROPFILES seems to be deprecated since 95'.

Comment: I must add that I just tried WM_DROPFILES and it "works" on photoshop but they handle the WM_DROPFILES by "opening" a new image. Which could be due to their outdated implementation of the WM_DROPFILES event. The desired effect would be creating a new layer for the image. However, this approach works great for Notepad. Having said that, the ole dnd approach fails for ms-word (pastes an image instead of txt file) and whereas postmessage works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse move/click is probably the best solution in this case. Here is something you can try. Assuming you are using windows since you put c# in the title

1. open up the folder
2. move mouse to the search box of the folder ( does not have to be hard coded coordinate, some GUI tool can recognize it)
3. use send string method to input the name of the file that you wish to import
4. move mouse to select the first result
5. mouse down
6. use either pixel detection or GUI tool's detection to determine the coordinate of the panel that you wish to drop on
7. drop it and do some error check.

OR

If you are an expert of Windows you can try to do some inter process communication to send the drag and drop event to the program.

Comment: Like I said in the question, I won't be automating the cursor; Believe me when I say that I've beaten that method to death... and then some. There are just too many things that can go wrong (for example, if the user has opened another pane in explorer, or similarly changed some view settings, it could shift the files around so that they are not in the same coordinates every time). Besides, I really see this as a workaround.

Your second suggestion is more the method I am willing to use; I'm not an expert in Windows, but I am familiar with the WinAPI.