# Pass Drop Event on to a Folder using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop, ole

I have a program that acts as a Drop-target for OLE Drag and Drop.
(Based on http://www.catch22.net/tuts/ole-data-transfers)

My Question is if it possible to pass on this Drop Event on a Folder - like Temp Folder. As in, the User drops on a GUI (which is the drop-target), this drop-target sends the drop to Explorer.

Something like sending Message to Folder -

```
SendMessage((HWND) folder_hwnd, WM_OLEDROP, (WPARAM)pDataObject, 0);   //Pseudo-code
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does "the User is dropping on the API" even mean? Are you sure you know what an API is?

Comment: I feel the Question is understandable. BUt to answer ur question - i know what an API is. 'the user dropping..." means the programm supports drag n drop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937330/simulate-windows-drag-and-drop-with-code/21938622#21938622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate a drag-and-drop onto a folder using the following steps:

1. Obtain the PIDL for the target folder e.g. using [`SHParseDisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Obtain an [`IShellFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075(v=vs.85).aspx) for the target folder e.g. using [`SHBindToObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762113(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. Bind to the folder's [`IDropTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface using [`IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775073(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can then simulate a drop to the folder using the various methods of the `IDropTarget` interface.